# C++ converting unsigned char array to long (or long long) in String representation

Tags: c++, arduino, type-conversion

I would like to convert `unsigned char testData[8] = {0xFF,0xF0,0x00,0xA0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x99};`
to a String (Arduino variable type)

Currently I try this:

```
  std::string str( reinterpret_cast<char*>(testData), 8);
  // std::string str( testData, testData + sizeof testData / sizeof testData[0] );
  String message = String(str.c_str());
```

But that returns the asci characters of the char values, which makes sense. But what I am trying to achieve is to interpret all the bits(8x8) from the array as a long long (64 bit int) and convert this numerical value to its string representation. I want to achieve this so I can send it in JSON to my nodejs server (which doesnt support 64 bits, so I will probably have to cut in two).

So for instance if I have : {0xFF,0xF0,0x00,0xA0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x99}
and its long long value for example is: 9894736399534 
then I would like to retrieve "9894736399534" in my String object.

Comment: So then interpret the memory as a long long and then convert it.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you come up with long long value for this unsigned char array

Comment: @Kapil It was just a random integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other have pointed out, all you have to do is interpret the raw data as an (unsigned) long long and then store the value in a string, for instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char testData[8] = {0xFF,0xF0,0x00,0xA0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x99};
    unsigned long long data = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(testData);

    std::stringstream str;
    //str << std::hex << data;
    str << data;

    std::cout << str.str() << '\n';

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT

The following solution relies on the `String` constructor to convert the original 64-bit value into 2 32-bit value representations that can either be concatenated or used separately if you need to.
This assumes that the platform is little-endian.

```
String lsdw = String(*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&testData[0]), HEX);
String msdw = String(*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&testData[4]), HEX);
String message = lsdw + msdw;
```

Comment: Hi Oliver thank you for your answer, I think this is what I am looking for, so I tryed it, and it does compile, however, when it starts to create a binary file it throws the following error: https://pastebin.com/mFDi7XbN any idea?

Comment: Apparently the error is due to stringstream not being supported on Arduino. I'll edit the message with an alternate solution that should work (according to the documentation).

Comment: Thank you so much man! That is working perfectly, I have been struggling with this for a week.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to reinterpret memory as 64bit `int` pointer then create a string from the number in that memory region.

So convert the `char*` to `unsigned long long*` then dereference it and create a string.

This code should work.

```
    unsigned long long number = *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long *>(testData))
    std::string stringNum = std::to_string(number);
```

Comment: How can you assign unsigned long long to string ?

Comment: This is not an assignment. This is a constructor call with one parameter of type `unsigned long long`

Comment: @Kapil Whoops. I should test my code before posting. However `operator <<` should work.

Comment: Have you tested this time? Bcoz I think extraction operator cannot be used directly with std::string

Answer (score 0):

I think with bitset this can be accomplished easily and here is sample code for the same :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <bitset>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char testData[8] = {0xFF,0xF0,0x00,0xA0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x99};
    std::cout<<"size of array is "<<sizeof(testData)<<std::endl;
    std::stringstream strStream;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<sizeof(testData);i++)
    {
      std::bitset<16> test(testData[i]);
      strStream<<test.to_ullong();

    }
    std::cout<<"Final string corresponding to this unsigned char array is "<<strStream.str()<<std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```